# how can I add a "like" button bar into my facebook app?

Tags: button, facebook-like, facebook-canvas

It is my first FB app and I really need some help. I can't figure out how to display a bar like this at the top of my app.

The screenshot's url is http://www.perideogroup.com/greenparty/like-button-bar.jpg